# Unable to get fetch response on react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm, fetch

I am stuck on one of the mysterious issue. The problem goes like this:

What I Do??
Simply do login api call and if login success then I have to fetch amount of data from 5-6 api calls and store them in local database (Realm). Here is my code.

```
login(email, password) {
    this.toggleLoadingFunction(true);

    fetch(LoginURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        request_from: 'mobile'
      }),
    })
      .then(async res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          let data = await res.json();

          global.user = data['user']
          global.token = data['token']

          getAllMasterDataAndSaveInRealm().then(() => {
            this.toggleLoadingFunction(false);
            global.storage.save({ key: 'LoggedInData', data: data });
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Project', data);
          }).catch(() => {
            this.toggleLoadingFunction(false);
            Alert.alert("Master Data Failed !!!");
          })

        } else {
          this.toggleLoadingFunction(false);
          let data = await res.json();
          Alert.alert("Login Failed!!!", data.message)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.toggleLoadingFunction(false);
        Alert.alert("Network Error. Please try again.")
      })
```

Here getAllMasterDataAndSaveInRealm() is lies on helper function which calls 5-6 apis and response back if all work is done. Here is how it looks like:

```
export const getAllMasterDataAndSaveInRealm = () => {
  const token = global.token;
  return new Promise.all([
    getMaterials(token),
    getEquipments(token),
    getObjective(token),

    getCategories(token),
    getNcData(token),
    getPlans(token)]
  );
}
```

Each function inside getAllMasterDataAndSaveInRealm() returns Promise after successfully stored data in local realm db. Here is one of the above function.

```
export const getActivityPlan = (token) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return fetch(FetchActivityPlanDataURL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'access_token': `${token}`
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log("Activity Plans Api response", response);
      return response.json()
    })
      .then((responseJson) => {
        const { data } = responseJson
        console.warn("Activity Plans Api", data);

        global.realm.write(() => {

          for (var item of data) {
            item.id = item.id ? item.id : 0;
            item.activity_id = item.activity_id ? item.activity_id.toString() : "";
            item.activity_name = item.activity_name ? item.activity_name.toString() : "";
            item.activity_cost = item.activity_cost ? item.activity_cost.toString() : "";
            item.project_id = item.project_id ? item.project_id : 0;

            global.realm.create("ActivityPlan", item, true);
          }

        })

        resolve(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(`Activity Plan Failed ${error}`)
      });
  })
}
```

All remaining functions are same as above ( what they do is simply fetch data from api and store it in realm and resolve or reject)

What I Expect: 
getAllMasterDataAndSaveInRealm() function Just store all the required data in db and let me know all done and then navigate to the another screen, as Login and fetching data is done.

Problem: 
When I do run the app and process for login, Sometimes it works fine but most of the time App stuck on showing loader since some of the api call among 6 api from above ***do not get response from the request ( I do log the response) on wifi***. ***But when I use mobile data and VPN it always works.***

When I log request on server console, response is sent with code 200, but app is unable to get response for the request.

I am new on react native. I do lots of searches over internet but unable to find the solution.  I don't have any idea whats going wrong with the code. Please help me out.

Project Configurations:
        "react": "16.8.6",
        "react-native": "0.60.4",
        "realm": "^2.29.2",
Node version: v9.0.0